# React how to toggle a button that is used in multiple parts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an icon that I toggle to close a tab

```
 <img src={upArrow} alt="" onClick={() => setCloseTabToggle(!closeTabToggle)} />
```

its state:

```
const [closeTabToggle, setCloseTabToggle] = useState(false)
```

To trigger the css:

```
<Form.Group className={closeTabToggle ? `closed-tab-true` : ''}>
```

Now this works okay with one icon, but what to do if I have multiple? Something like `this` in jquery

Comment: Can you share your full code. It seems like you might need indexing. But I think making the toggle an independent component would be a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing a single boolean in closeTabToggle, you could instead store an array of booleans.

```
const [toggleArray, setToggleArray] = useState([false, false, false]);
```

Each of the boolean values can correspond to each of your clickable icons.
If all your icons are the same components, you could map over the toggleArray and render an icon for each item.

```
{toggleArray.map((item, i) => (
        <img key={i} src={upArrow} alt="" onClick={() => {
          handleIconClick(i);
        }} />
      ))}
```

handleIconClick would look like this:

```
const handleIconClick = (i) => {
    const temp = [...toggleArray];
    temp[i] = !temp[i];
    setToggleArray(temp);
  };
```

So clicking an icon will change the corresponding boolean with the same index in the toggleArray.

Finally, to change the classNames for your Form.Group elements.

```
<Form.Group className={toggleArray[0] ? `closed-tab-true` : ''}/>
<Form.Group className={toggleArray[1] ? `closed-tab-true` : ''}/>
<Form.Group className={toggleArray[2] ? `closed-tab-true` : ''}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way if want to handle multiple tabs with different image

```
const [tab, setTab] = useState(1)
```

Set the unique id for each tab

```
<img src={upArrow} alt="" onClick={()=>setTab(1)} />
<img src={upArrow} alt="" onClick={()=>setTab(2)} />
<img src={upArrow} alt="" onClick={()=>setTab(3)} />
```

then hide and show based on your css

```
<Form.Group className={tab===1 ? `d-block` : 'd-none'}>One</Form.Group>
<Form.Group className={tab===2 ? `d-block` : 'd-none'}>two</Form.Group>
<Form.Group className={tab===3 ? `d-block` : 'd-none'}>three</Form.Group>
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it will reopen all the other ones when one is closed