# How can I open dropdowns separately in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list, and I have dropdowns in this list. But because their state is the same, clicking a dropdown opens the others. What is the way to open this separately? We'll probably use id but I haven't figured out exactly how to do it. By the way, reactstrap is used in the project, so I'm trying to do it using reactstrap.

```
  const toggleModal1 = () => setModal1(!modal1);

<Table className="no-wrap v-middle" responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr className="border-0">
                <th className="border-0">Ünvan</th>
                <th className="border-0">TCK/Vergi No</th>
                <th className="border-0">E-Posta</th>
                <th className="border-0">Ad</th>
                <th className="border-0">Soyad</th>
                <th className="border-0">İşlemler</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {companies?.map((val) => (
                <tr key={val.Id}>
                  <td>
                    <span>{val.Name}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span>{val.TCKN_VN}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span>{val.ElectronicMail}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span>{val.FirstName}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <span>{val.FamilyName}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <Dropdown
                      toggle={(e) => handleDropdownToggle(e,val.Id)}
                      direction="left"
                      id={val.Id}
                    >
                      <DropdownToggle caret>
                        <i className="fas fa-cogs"></i>
                      </DropdownToggle>
                      <DropdownMenu>
                        <DropdownItem onClick={toggleModal1}>
                          Şirket Düzenle
                        </DropdownItem>
                        <DropdownItem onClick={(e) => removeCompany(e, val.Id)}>
                          Şirket Sil
                        </DropdownItem>
                      </DropdownMenu>
                    </Dropdown>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>

<Modal isOpen={modal1} toggle={toggleModal1}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={toggleModal1}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
            eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
            ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
            aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
            reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
            culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={toggleModal1}>
              Do Something
            </Button>{" "}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggleModal1}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
```

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174418/react-how-to-toggle-a-button-that-is-used-in-multiple-parts/66175014#66175014

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer, there is a tag called UncontrolledDropdown in ReactStrap. So you can do it like this:

```
<UncontrolledDropdown>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        Dropdown
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem disabled>Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider />
        <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
</UncontrolledDropdown>
```

Comment: You can also use a controlled Dropdown, but then you would have to separate the state, so that each dropdown, hat ist own `open`state